# beginner Python program using count-based iteration structure

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am in a beginner Python programming class and we were to write a program that generates an item description, it's price, and the total. The program I originally wrote used LISTS which landed me a fat 0 for the assignment because apparently we were not to use lists on this assignment. Fortunately for me I get to rewrite it. SO, I am supposed to use a count-based iteration structure, I can use the “for” statement, or both the “for” and “while” statements. But NOT just the “while” statement alone ( count based not event based). I do not know which combination would be most effective. I have attached my program but I do not think it is very good at all, the structure just seems bad to me. If anyone could give me some guidance on how I could make this look better, or how I could improve it I would appreciate it immensely. I have searched high and low for an example that doesn't include lists or some crazy stuff (I am a beginner so we use beginner things) but have had no luck at all.
Lastly, I would like to say again, I CANNOT use LISTS, thank you all in advance.

**The Problem:**

Utilise a count-based iteration structure that will accepts the data listed below and produce the total purchase amount.  Your final report should be similar to the one show below.

Input Data:

```
Item Description    Item Price
Salomon Fish        $ 26.97
Ribeye Steak        $ 12.98
Sweet Corn          $ 4.96
Asparagus           $ 5.92
```

Output:

```
Item Description       Item Price

=================================

Salomon Fish            $ 26.97

Ribeye Steak            $ 12.98

Sweet Corn              $ 4.96

Asparagus               $ 5.92

Your total purchase: $ xx.xx
```

**My Code:** (sorry if formatting is wrong, I have never posted on here)

```
fish=int(input("enter fish price ===> "))
corn=int(input("enter corn price ===> "))
steak=int(input("enter steak price ===> "))
asparagus=int(input("enter asparagus price ===> "))
for x in range (1,fish+1,1):
    total=x
for y in range(1,corn+1,1):
    total=x+y
for z in range(1,steak+1,1):
    total=x+y+z
for i in range(1,asparagus+1,1):
    total=x+y+z+i
print("Item Description   Item Price")
print("==============================")
print("Fish              $",fish)
print("Corn              $",corn)
print("Steak             $",steak)
print("Asparagus         $",asparagus)
print("Your Total Purchase:", total)
```

the output is:

```
enter fish price ===> 5
enter corn price ===> 5
enter steak price ===> 5
enter asparagus price ===> 5
Item Description   Item Price
==============================
Fish              $ 5
Corn              $ 5
Steak             $ 5
Asparagus         $ 5
Your Total Purchase: 20
```

Comment: Nice job formatting and asking question. I wish I could be more helpful, but that problem description seems poor to me. When it says "it will accept data" it's not really clear how that data will arrive (if not a list). You are using an `input()`, but that's not that common in the real world. Perhaps they expect you to use the `input()` in a loop and have the user provide the description and price for each item rather than hard-coding `fish` `corn`, etc.

Comment: (1) We need you to include the problem description so your question is self-contained; off-site links are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.
(2) If you have a specific question, please focus on that.  This is more of a code review request, which would go to StackExchange.CodeReview.

Comment: What is a "count-based iteration structure"?  Is that the `for` loop?  If so, what are you supposed to count?

Comment: @Prune Okay, thank you for the info! I am new here :-) and yes it can include the for and while loops. Just not the while loop alone.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I asked my teacher about how he would like us to go about approaching the question, however he did not answer my question very directly (no offense to him he is very nice just not straight forward). I honestly think we can choose to have user input or to not have user input. But it doesn't really make sense to me how to write it without user input. Thank you for your commentary!

Comment: I'm worried that the instructor *wants* you to deal with input quantities, such as `fish_quant = input("How many fish?")`.  Then you would compute the total price of all fish bought, with either a simple multiplication, or a `for` loop.

Comment: I understand that you can use loops.  I simply don't see *why* you would use a loop.  What are you supposed to count?

Comment: @Prune I honestly don't know why he chose this assignment for this particular area we are covering. I have had no issue writing any of the other programs he has given us. I can usually figure this stuff out on my own but I really don't understand what he is looking for. I thought it was just me overthinking the problem but maybe it was not after all! I really appreciate the help you have offered... I will continue to trial and error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concur with `Mark Meyer`: the assignment does not specify the input.  You've done well enough with your programming style.  Given the restrictions, I suggest only a couple of improvements:

- Use a running total variable for the sum.
- Give it a meaningful name.  x, y, z are meaningless.

Here, the running tally would look something like:

```
total = 0
total += fish
total += corn
...
```