# Printing user output with while loop/beginner Python

Tags: python, while-loop, output, user-input

hopefully there is a simple answer for this. How can I take user input from a while loop and print all of the input (without using lists when writing this)? Is there a way to output this information when the number of executions from the user is unknown? I am only a beginner so if there is a simple way to do this just using basics please let me know!

Here is an example of what I am trying to ask:

Say I am asking the user for the name and price of an item. They have the option to enter more items, or stop the execution. Then the output would list the name of the items, the prices, and their total amount purchased. I would like to print out all of these items that they have inputted.

Output formatted something like this:

```
Item Name      Item Price
Soap           $ 3.98
Detergent      $ 6.99
Chips          $ 2.50
....
....
Your Total: $xx.xx
```

I know how to do everything else, just having issues displaying all of their given input after they stop the execution. Just needing some guidance in this area. Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify. Thanks in advance!
I am using Python 3.

Comment: "without using lists" - Why? If each item name is unique, you could use a dict. If it's not guaranteed to be, using lists in some way would be the simplest thing to do.

Comment: If you cannot store it in a list then I'd store it in a multiline string. Otherwise I'd just print each line after every input. Would be helpful if you wrote some code for us to work with

Comment: If you need to store the user inputs  and then display them when you're done, lists are a natural way to do it.  Can you explain why you can't use lists?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille This is part of a class assignment. I used lists on an assignment (they do make more sense) and my teacher gave me a 0 because we haven't went over them in class yet. He gave us an example like this assignment in class but did not go over formatting the output, this is why I ask. I wish I could use lists!

Comment: @JohnGordon I am not supposed to use lists sense we haven't went over them in our class, although they are much easier to use in this circumstance. I may just end up turning in what I have and hope for the best! I asked my instructor about this question and he just told me to look at the class notes. Sadly, I have inspected those notes quite thoroughly with no luck

Comment: If you're prohibited from using lists, there are other ways to do it.  You could write the items to a temporary file, you could use a tuple (which _technically_ is not a list), you could store them all in some giant string with newlines in between the items.  But those methods are quite unnatural ways to solve the problem and are more complicated too, so I wonder what point the teacher is trying to make here.

Comment: Thank you for all of your input. I will most likely turn in the program I have written already. I have looked and looked for a simple way to do this but not too much luck with it!

Comment: I read [your previous question about this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830081/beginner-python-program-using-count-based-iteration-structure) and I would still have the same questions as the ones that were asked in the comments, regarding how the input is supposed to be, and what your task exactly is. As a teacher myself, I would consider it a poorly designed task. Sorry that we can't help you more, and good luck with that...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes, this assignment was much more unclear than all of the past ones. I spoke to others in my class and they did not make well on it either. I have really tried my best to find info to write the program how he wants, but I am uncertain of what he is looking for. Hopefully he will decide to scale the grade since others are having the same issue.

Comment: Anyway, as already said, congratulations for the well explained, well formatted questions and your reactivity to comments. That's a pleasant change from many questions we get. So, welcome!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thank you! Everyone has been very helpful and I appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand so well but I think you can use:

```
bill = ''
total_price = 0
while True:
    
    item = input('(If Done Write Exit) Item Name: ')
    if item == "exit":
        break
    price = input("price: ")

    bill = bill + "Item: "+item + '\nPrice: ' + price + '\n\n'

    total_price += int(price)
print('\n'*4)
print(bill+'\n\nTotal Price:',total_price)
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'price' is not defined`, among other errors that this untested piece of code will raise.

Comment: Sorry I have Forgotten The ""

Comment: This Will give a error at bill.append(item, price), this logic seems wrong, have you tested your code?

Comment: Fixed Just a Second Ago

Comment: The question states explicitely "without using lists" - the reason why is explained in the comments. So, sorry, but your answer doesn't answer the question...

Comment: Check It Again.

Comment: Well, considering the constraints, that would be a way. As a side note for your future answers: please test your code before answering. And as another side note, please, please don't try to run any `pip install` if an import fails! ;)

Comment: well it is my first hour in stackoverflow so this is expected and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So I hope this matches what you were asking for.
I used nested dictionries, incase you want more info per item, but I mean you can also use tuples if you want.

```
prompts = ["Item name", "Item price"]
flag = True
items = {}
indx = 0

while flag:
    inp = input("Type 'new' to register a new item or 'exit' to exit ")
    if inp == "new":
        output = {}
        for p in prompts:
            inp = input(p)
            output[p] = inp
        indx += 1
        items[indx] = output
        
    if inp == "exit":
        flag = False
```

This is fairly simple, but to explain the steps;
Typing new allows you to start entering a new item.
It asks the prompts that are listed in the prompts list.
(It also uses these prompts to name the values in the output dict)

Once all the data is in, it'll be indexed and added into the items dict.

Then the loop begins again. You can add the new item, or type exit to stop entering items.

Edit:
Also I decided to use a flag instead of breaks so you can modify if you want more stop conditions.